# Is there a way to turn off autocomplete for SQL in Databricks (it is awful)?

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql, databricks-notebook

We recently got an update for our Databricks Notebooks web pages that now seems to include an autocomplete for SQL that is very distracting.

Is there a way to turn this feature off.

These articles don't seem to have information on how to turn this feature off:

https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-code.html

https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-editor.html

[image]

[image]

--- EDIT ------------------------------------------------
My UI looked a little different that what the accepted answer described.  This worked for me (turn off autocomplete):

[image]

Comment: You've used the wrong screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I did it today
click on your username at the top right of your workspace
Select User Settings
Click the Editor Settings tab
Then deselect the option next to **Turn on the notebook editor**